# Defining a delegate in a UIView/UIViewController relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have a subclassed UIView called TargetView that is contained in a UIViewController called MainViewController. I want to set MainViewController as the delegate for TargetView so that MainViewController can receive messages from the child view (TargetView).

In my MainViewController (UIViewController) header I have the following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TargetView.h"

@class TargetView;

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <TargetViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet TargetView *target;    
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblResults;

@end
```

When I set the TargetViewDelegate in the interface declaration, it shows up in code completion so it knows that it's there, but then the build fails with the message: can't find protocol declaration..."

In my TargetView (UIView) class I have the following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MainViewController.h"

@protocol TargetViewDelegate

@required
-(void)receivedTargetTap;

@end

@interface TargetView : UIView{

    id<TargetViewDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *lblResults;
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<TargetViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Creating custom delegates is uncharted territory for me. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to change your @protocol with : *@protocol TargetViewDelegate <NSObject>* ?

Comment: I'll post an answer with some edits to your code.

Comment: You need to add <NSObject> after the declaration of the del.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your TargetView.h should be :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol TargetViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)receivedTargetTap;

@end

@interface TargetView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lblResults;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<TargetViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

MainViewController.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TargetView.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <TargetViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet TargetView *target;    
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblResults;

@end
```

---

From your code, you must add `<NSObject>` after your protocol definition, and remove the `MainViewController.h` import in your TargetView class.

Comment: Still get the same message: cannot find protocol declaration for TargetViewController

Comment: You said "TargetViewController" but there is no such TargetViewController on your code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant TargetViewDelegate

Comment: @Pheepster : I just tried the full code I posted in a blank project, and it works. As Romain said, it might be because you tried to *#import "MainViewController.h"* in TargetView. Can you retry this code ?

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be a problem with your `import` statements in both `.h` files.

Why do you reference `MainViewController.h` from `TargetView.h`? It seems like you don't need it. On the other hand, you should remove the forward declaration of `@class TargetView` in `MainViewController.h`, and the simple `#import "TargetView.h"` should be enough.

After that, you'll also need to implement the required `- (void)receivedTargetTap;`, otherwise the compiler will complain again that the `TargetViewDelegate` is not fully implemented.

Comment: You are right, it seems that the MainViewController.h import is causing the problem.